# Typescript issue during compilation around `webpack/HashedModuleIdsPlugin`

Tags: typescript, webpack

I am getting compilation issue around `HashedModuleIdsPlugin` and `typescript` :(

When compiling a TS project that allow JS, requires `HashedModuleIdsPlugin` and export it using commonJS, it raises an error and is not able to produce proper declaration files.

I reproduced it in a super tiny project here: https://github.com/raphaelboukara/test_ts_webpack.

In my `src` folder I have 2 files:

- `index.ts`: import `webpack.js`
- `webpack.js`: exports `require('webpack').ids.HashedModuleIdsPlugin`

```
// ./src/index.ts
import "./webpack.js";
```

```js
// ./src/webpack.js
const { ids: { HashedModuleIdsPlugin } } = require('webpack');
module.exports = HashedModuleIdsPlugin;
```

```json
{
  "exclude": [
    "dist"
  ],
  "include": [
    "./src"
  ],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "declaration": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "allowJs": true,
    "outDir": "dist"
  }
}
```

When running `tsc`, I am getting the error:

```
src/webpack.js:1:1 - error TS9006: Declaration emit for this file requires using private name 'HashedModuleIdsPlugin' from module '"/Users/raphael.b/lab/test_ts_webpack/node_modules/webpack/types"'. An explicit type annotation may unblock declaration emit.

1 const { ids: { HashedModuleIdsPlugin } } = require('webpack');
  ~~~~~


Found 1 error in src/webpack.js:1
```

#### How to reproduce?

1. git clone git@github.com:raphaelboukara/test_ts_webpack.git
2. nvm use
3. npm i
4. npm run build

#### Environment

- node: 16.13.1
- webpack: 5.72.0
- ts: 4.6.4

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: This is a Typescript error. I'm having this error currently. I came here through the link you posted on Gitter.
Found a solution?

Comment: have you been able to resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> requires using private name 'HashedModuleIdsPlugin' from module '"/Users/raphael.b/lab/test_ts_webpack/node_modules/webpack/types"'

Typescript is complaining because `HashedModuleIdsPlugin` is not explicitly exported from the webpack library. It is only re-exported as a property under `ids` and `ids` is explicitly exported from webpack. That's why Typescript says that it is **private**. It wasn't explicitly made to be accessible directly from the library in the types as you are trying to do here

```js
const { ids: { HashedModuleIdsPlugin } } = require('webpack');
```

So what you should do is access it from `ids` and export it so

```js
// webpack.js
const { ids } = require('webpack');
module.exports = ids.HashedModuleIdsPlugin;
```

You may want to enable `compilerOptions.esModuleInterop` by setting it to `true` in your `tsconfig.json` if you want to do something like

```js
// webpack.js
const { ids } = require('webpack');
module.exports = { HashedModuleIdsPlugin: ids.HashedModuleIdsPlugin }
```

```js
// index.ts
import { HashedModuleIdsPlugin } from "./webpack.js";
```

Comment: Yes! thanks a lot! it seems you are totally right. I don't understand what do you mean when you say "HashedModuleIdsPlugin is not explicitly exported"?

In [webpack types](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/e2df0ddd922520fc7a4df07492588af8128c3b2a/types.d.ts#L12711-L12723) they did:
```
declare namespace exports {
  ...
  export namespace ids {
  export {
   ...
   HashedModuleIdsPlugin
  };
 }
...
}
What they can do more than that? What they are missing?

Comment: I think VSCode is pulling information from the types, and in the types, `HashedModuleIdsPlugin` is a property of `ids`. I don't see `HashedModuleIdsPlugin` being exported, rather it is a property. So if one wants to use it, it'll be extracted from the property (of `ids`).
Remember, this is not a JS error. @RaphaelBoukara

Comment: But why do you say `HashedModuleIdsPlugin` type is not exported? it's exported [here](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/e2df0ddd922520fc7a4df07492588af8128c3b2a/types.d.ts#L12721). I don't understand :(

Comment: Look at the file again. It is exported in the **TYPES** _.d.ts_ as a property of `ids`. You can read my answer and my last comment. They explain it, kinda. The emphasis is on NO EXPLICIT EXPORT from the js file and EXPORT UNDER `ids` from the types file